# How to add variable into html tag in nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to add variable into html tag in nodemailer without html templates?

```
var my = "my var";

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "mailer",
port: 587,
secure: false,
auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'pass',
},
});
let info = transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"some adds" <email>',
    to: "email", // list of receivers
    subject: "some subject", // Subject line
    text: "some text", // plain text body
    html: "<p>paste variable here like ${my}</p>",// html body
});
console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use template strings:

```js
var my = "my var";

console.log(`<p>paste variable here like ${my}</p>`);
```